# Google Script: Sort Array of Email Addresses to Remove Duplicates

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I pull data from a Google Event Calendar. The events include multiple point of contact e-mails (Primary, Secondary, etc.)

I am currently able to collect ALL of the e-mails for the events, and this includes many duplicates.

I would like to take the entire list of emails (currently delimited by ";") and parse through to remove the duplicates.

I created a call function that takes a string (the current list of e-mails) and should return a clean list.

The code I have been trying to use:

```
function CleanEmail (InputEmailString) {
              var ReturnEmail = "";
              var EmailArray = [];
              var EmailArray = InputEmailString.split(";");
              EmailArray.sort().reverse();
              var ReturnEmail = EmailArray[0];
                for (i=1; i < EmailArray.length; ++i) {
                    if (EmailArray[i-1] != EmailArray[i]) {
                    ReturnEmail += ";" + EmailArray[i]
                    }            // End If Statement
                  }              // End For Statement
               return ReturnEmail;  
          }                      // Close Function
```

My thought is to sort the Array so that it would be in alphabetical order, then check one email back to see if there is a duplicate.

Regardless of what I try the returned email list does not sort, nor does it remove any duplicates.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: If you are using `.getGuestList()` it will return an array of `EventGuest`s. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getguestlist

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Using `Set` you can create an array of unique values.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let InputEmailString = "joe@someSite.com;mary@someOther.com;tom@another.com;joe@someSite.com;larry@stillAnother.com;joe@someSite.com;;tom@another.com;";
    CleanEmail(InputEmailString);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function CleanEmail (InputEmailString) {
  var ReturnEmail = "";
  var EmailArray = [];
  var EmailArray = InputEmailString.split(";");
  EmailArray = [...new Set(EmailArray)];
  EmailArray.sort().reverse();
  var ReturnEmail = EmailArray.join(';')
  console.log(ReturnEmail);
} // Close Function
```

**Execution Log**

```
11:29:51 AM Notice  Execution started
11:29:51 AM Info    tom@another.com;mary@someOther.com;larry@stillAnother.com;joe@someSite.com;
11:29:51 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: I have tried this and the other examples and still have not had success. I start with 50 e-mail addresses in the string and end up with the same number when the function is called. 

I have not had any success. 

So, now I am questioning whether the string is actually being passed/parsed properly.

Comment: As you can see I tested it with a string of random email address and it worked.

Comment: Maybe they're not seperated by ';' which would give you one element of the array.

Comment: Figured it out. I had an error in my code and was passing incorrect separators. Rookie mistake. Thanks for all of the codes and they work awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just taking a string of emails separated by `;`'s > removing duplicates > rejoining them,

### Try:

```
function CleanEmail (InputEmailString) {

   return [...new Set(InputEmailString.split(`;`)].join(`;`)

}
```

### Long Version:

```
function CleanEmail (InputEmailString) {

   const emailsArray = InputEmailString.split(`;`);
   const uniqueEmailsArray = [...new Set(emailArray)];
   const uniqueEmailString = uniqueEmailsArray.join(`;`);

   return uniqueEmailString 

}
```

### .getGuestList() Method

```
// const guestList = event.getGuestList()
// const emailList = CleanEmail(guestList)

function CleanEmail (guestListData) {

   const emailList = guestListData.map(i => i.getEmail())

   return [...new Set(emailList)].join(`;`)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Remove Duplicates

```
function removedup(eA=["email1@gmail.com","email1@gmail.com"]) {
  let uA = [];
  eA.forEach(e => {
    if (!~uA.indexOf(e)) {
      uA.push(e);
    }
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(uA));
  return uA;
}

Execution log
11:50:44 AM Notice  Execution started
11:50:44 AM Info    ["email1@gmail.com"]
11:50:45 AM Notice  Execution completed
```